# C# methods with multiple return parameters

Tags: c#, .net, language-design

Is there a need for multiple return parameters in c#/.net?

```
public string, string GetFirstNameAndLastName(int id)
{
    var person = from p in People
                 where p.Id = id
                 select p;
    return(p.FirstName, p.LastName);
}
```

Usage:

```
public void Main(string[] args)
{
    string firstName, lastName;
    (firstName, lastName) = GetFirstNameAndLastName(1);

    Console.WriteLine(firstName + ", " + lastName);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to return the firstName & lastName as separate values? Shouldn't they be represented in a Person instance? FirstName and LastName are properties of a Person object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by [@James Webster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561470/c-methods-with-multiple-return-parameters/5561489#5561489) you can use tuple or you can use `dynamic` and `ExpandoObject`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var d = GetUserDynamic();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}", d.FirstName, d.LastName);
    }

    private static dynamic GetUserDynamic()
    {
        dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
        d.FirstName = "amandeep";
        d.LastName = "tur";
        return d;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. It's simple and easy to understand. The obvious downside is no static type checking.

Comment: @Jonathan Parker if you have few things to return then you should not worry too much.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this in a lightweight fashion using Tuple in C# 4.0

```
public Tuple<string, string> GetFirstNameAndLastName(int id)
{
   var person = from p in People
             where p.Id = id
             select p;
   return new Tuple<string, string>(p.FirstName, p.LastName);

   // OR
   // return Tuple.Create(p.FirstName, p.LastName);
}
```

`System.Tuple` also has the benefit of interoperating with F# native tuple type (well, it IS F#'s native tuple type, there just happens to be F#-specific syntax support for declaring tuples and functions that return them).

Given the existence of multiple approaches here: `System.Tuple`, multiple `out` parameters or returning a POCO with `FirstName` and `LastName` properties, I suspect that Anders Hejlsberg is probably not going to add explicit support for multiple return values.

Comment: @James I believe you can use Tuple.Create(p.FirstName, p.LastName) to avoid having to specify the generic parameters.

Comment: Yep, just updated to reflect that ;-)

Comment: @James: The only problem with Tuples is the nasty `.Item1` and `.Item2` properties to get the components.  Makes the code slightly less readable.

Comment: ... especially since they start counting from 1, an not from 0 like common for arrays f.e.

Comment: `System.Tuple` also has the benefit of interoperating with F# native tuple type (well, it IS F#'s native tuple type, there just happens to be F#-specific syntax suppotr for declaring tuples and functions that return them.

Comment: I know abut Tuple but it's so ugly to use. It gives no indication to the code using the method of what the tuple contains.

Answer (score 5):

No, just use `out` parameters.

```
public void GetFirstNameAndLastName(int id, out string first, out string last)
{
    var person = from p in People
                 where p.Id = id
                 select p;
    first = p.FirstName;
    last = p.LastName;
}
```

Comment: your function signature looks suspicious

Comment: I don't see the reason for the other answers this one seems obvious, simple, and straightforward.

Comment: @user492238: Yup, got a little carried away with copy and paste there. :-)

Answer (score 1):

No. You should return a more useful data type like a class if the elements are related.

```
public MyPersonClassGetFirstNameAndLastName(int id)
{
    var person = from p in People
                 where p.Id = id
                 select p;

    MyPersonClassreturnValue = new MyPersonClass;
    returnValue.FirstName = p.FirstName; 
    returnValue.LastName= p.LastName;
    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Next to the possibilities pointed out in other answers, there is are more ways to archieve this:

1. create your own return type (similar to the Tuple method) and return an instance of it
2. ref parameters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the situation. In your case you could return the whole person record back,

```
public string, string GetFirstNameAndLastName(int id)
{
    var person = from p in People
             where p.Id = id
             select p;
    return person;
}
```

or if the situation required it you could create your own data type.

Answer (score -1):

You can do what you want like this:

```
public void GetFirstNameAndLastName(int id, out string firstName, out string lastName)
{
    var person = from p in People
                 where p.Id = id
                 select p;
    firstName = p.FirstName;
    lastName =  p.LastName;
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
public void Main(string[] args)
{
    string firstName, lastName;
    GetFirstNameAndLastName(1, out firstName, out lastName);

    Console.WriteLine(firstName + ", " + lastName);
}
```

Comment: Who did a -1 on this? I am not a big fan of out parameters, but I would like to hear from the down voter.